# Travelling on Advance Parole

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, pakistani-citizens

I'm a Pakistani residing in US and last year, I got married to a US-citizen.
I applied for permanent residence, and I'm currently waiting for the final interview before the green card is issued.

But for the meantime, I have been issued an advance parole by the US Department of Homeland Security. According to Google, I can travel abroad and re-enter US, no issues.

But I need to be sure that it won't abandon my green card application...

Can anyone, who has traveled on advance parole, shed some light on what else do I require?

Comment: Your question seems to be mixing up permanent residence (green card) with citizenship.

Comment: sorry, not citizenship.. updated the question..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that's the whole point of Advance Parole -- so you can travel abroad and return to the US while your Adjustment of Status is pending without abandoning your Adjustment of Status application.